# prove $S^{-1}(M \otimes N) \cong M\otimes S^{-1}N $?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

using $S^{-1}R \otimes M \cong S^{-1}M$ I have showed that
$$S^{-1}(M \otimes N) \cong  S^{-1}M\otimes N$$ but can't show 
$$S^{-1}(M \otimes N) \cong  M\otimes S^{-1}N$$?

Comment: If you can show that $S^{-1}(M\otimes N)\cong S^{-1}M\otimes N$, then certainly you can show that $S^{-1}(M\otimes N)\cong M\otimes S^{-1}N$, since $M\otimes N\cong N\otimes M$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use $M\otimes N\cong N\otimes M$ twice, as well as the result you have already proven.